# Custom Rules for Stylecop in .net Core 2.0

Tags: stylecop

I am trying to determine how to create a completely custom rule using Stylecop.Analyzers for .net Core 2.0.

I have figured out how to change the reporting (warning, error, none) and have setup a custom rule set that is shared across all my projects to save my settings for existing rules.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a new rule that is not in the "rules" files.
As an example - would it be possible to create a rule that says all static names must being with a lower case s.